# How can I refresh the cache for static resources in Communities?

Tags: lightning, community, static-resources, bug

I have updated a static resource with a new file and kept the reference (using url not $Resource) the same.
The updated resource was not loaded, even when I left it over the weekend.
Even deleting the static resource has kept the resource in the community cache for some reason.

This seems like a bug, but is there also a way to refresh the cache in the pointer  to static resources for community?

Comment: Did you try force reload? (`CTRL` + `F5`). Usually I use a guest window in chrome to test cache issues with static resource. Also using `$Resource.StaticResourceName` is a best practice.

Comment: I've tried force resetting the browser and testing on different computer as well.
I'm fully aware of the $Resource method, but I'm just wondering if there is a way to pull the latest version so I don't have to change the code and push change sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you're saying that you're directly including a static resource in a community with a url like `/resources/my_resource_png` instead of using the preferred format of `{!URLFOR($Resource.my_resource_png)}`.

One reason to prefer the second is that it generates the actual URL based on the last modified time of the resource. So it renders as something like `/resource/1535031348000/my_resource_png`. Part of the reason for that is so that browsers know not to use the cached version if the last modified version has changed - uploading a new version of the resource changes the URL.

The fact that you get the same version is not a bug in SF, in fact it's nothing to do with SF, it's all about the browser.

If you really cannot use the `{!URLFOR($Resource.my_resource_png)}`, you can always just throw your own version number on the end of an explicit reference e.g. `/resources/my_resource_png?v2`. I would strongly encourage you to use `$Resource`, though,

**Edit**

Questioner has clarified that they'd using Lightning. In Lightning, you refer to the resource like this:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.my_resource_png}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"
/>
```

That has the same effect as what I described above for Visualforce.

Comment: I'm using <ltng:require> for loading the scripts from static resource like <ltng:require styles="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.css"
        scripts="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.js"
        afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}"/>

Comment: OK, thanks, I've updated my question. That does show why it's useful to share your code in the question!

Comment: I'm fully aware of using scripts="{!$Resource.my_resource_png}", I'm just wondering if there is  a way to refresh the cache or get the latest version automatically without having to change every reference to the static resource that uses scripts="/resource/my_resource.png".
Particularly in Communities it doesn't refresh.

Comment: But why would you use scripts="/resource/my_resource.png" in the first place? It's just the wrong way to reference a resource, so unless you actually have to do it that way, the best answer is just to switch all your resources over to the right way. Other solutions, like the hard-refresh of the browser above, aren't feasible for a live community because you can't ask all your users to do that

Comment: It's legacy code and would just be easier than changing every reference. That is all.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I think you'll have to bite the bullet and change them all, though. You can defeat browser behaviour, and it will probably keep biting you in the future until you do change it. In a decent IDE, that won't take long. In Illuminated Cloud, it would be a 5 minute job to do a global search + replace.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you and will do so going forward. However, I feel this is a bug with Salesforce/Lightning/Communities caching static resource but wanted to confirm this first.

Comment: Fantastic answer, learnt something new. Thank you!