# How to obtain updated static resource referenced by LWC in Communities/Experience page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, static-resources, experience-cloud

After updating a static resource and importing it using `import nameOfResource from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/nameOfResource";`, only the FIRST version is what is obtained and not any subsequent updated versions, even after emptying the browser cache and performing a hard reload.

There is a solution with Aura [How can I refresh the cache for static resources in Communities?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232757/how-can-i-refresh-the-cache-for-static-resources-in-communities)

But is there an LWC solution for this? The link above only applies to Aura, but how can I obtain the latest version of the static resource for LWC in Community/Experience pages?

Answer (score 0):

Communities cache all the used resources (scripts, etc) that are presented to the client. You need to actually Publish the site to get any new changes to be updated.